# Error when creating a Deposit in Quickbooks via Quickbooks-ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

i'm trying to create a deposit in quickbooks, here's the code

```
deposit = Quickbooks::Model::Deposit.new
deposit.total = amount

line_item = Quickbooks::Model::DepositLineItem.new
line_item.amount = amount

deposit.deposit_to_account_ref = {:value => 40, :name => "Checking"}
deposit.line_items = Array.new
deposit.line_items << line_item

result = service.create(deposit)
```

I have used similar code to create a payment and it works perfectly UNTIL I ADD LINE ITEMS

the Error I'm getting:

System Failure Error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"

Usually the cause of this error is when you're trying to insert an object into an array that doesn't exist.

in the code for deposit.rb

https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/blob/master/lib/quickbooks/model/deposit.rb

```
xml_accessor :line_items, :from => 'Line', :as => [DepositLineItem]
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  The Line Item Requires a DepositDetailItem to be spcified within it.  Unless that's specified, QB sees the Line Items as blank, hence the out of index error.